# "Attending Events displays stored data" or "Attending Events display stored data"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I am having a discussion with my manager over the correct verbiage to display in a dialog on a mobile application. Could you please help us identify which statement is correct in the English language and also the reason why the 's' is or is not required in the word *displays.*

- Option 1 (mine): "Attending Events displays stored data."
- Option 2 (his): "Attending Events display stored data."

To provide some context around the verbiage being displayed in the dialog, the dialog displays on a page in the mobile application that user is viewing is called "Attending Events". This page displays a list of events that the user has marked as attending. Since the data is stored when the user is offline we need to provide the user a informational dialog with the correct verbiage as this is a business requirement.

Comment: Since _Attending Events_ is a totally context-free noun phrase, it's completely unknown whether it's singular or plural. Is it the action of attending events, or is the number of events that are attending? For starts. Given that neither of your suggested labels means anything, I think it's a waste of attention to worry about something irrelevant like verb agreement.

Comment: @JohnLawler The dialog displays on a page in the mobile application that user is viewing is called "Attending Events". This page displays a list of events that the user has marked as attending. Since the data is stored when the user is offline we need to provide the user a informational dialog with the correct verbiage as this is a business requirement.

Comment: If *Attending Events* could usefully be enclosed in quotation marks in your message, then surely it's singular. In fact you might actually consider quotation marks.

Comment: "Attending Events" is the label for the field so let's replace "Attending Events" with "label"..."the label displays stored data".  You win! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Attending Events displays stored data" is the correct way because displays is a verb in present tense, like walks or talks.

In the present tense:

I   display

you display

he;she;it   displays

If you said "Attending events Will..." then display could go without the S.